# Force two last bars down in figure of stacked bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

I want to illustrate data with stacked bars using tikz in ShareLaTeX. I'm working with two files: a data file called "Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt" and the document where I'm working in called "Crowdfunding.tex". I have data containing the different types of crowdfunding for the first three years, but only have the total value for the last two years. The data in the txt file looks like this:

```
year Donation Equity Lending Reward Mixed-others Total

2010 460.4 49.9 316.5 15.7 0 
2011 675.7 88.9 554.9 61.5 0
2012 979.4 115.7 1169.7 383.3 2.4
2013 0 0 0 0 0 6100
2014 0 0 0 0 0 16200
```

where I've plotted in 0's for the the different types. (Also tried forcing the last two bars by replacing the 0's with "." but didn't work. Currently the output looks like this:

[image]

I would like to accomplish four things: 1) force the two yellow bars to USD bn = 0 2) spread the labels to one line 3) remove the upper and top axis (so only the labeled axis remain 4) insert labels inside the last two bars (6,2 for the bar on 2013 and 16,2 for the bar in 2014).

This is my code:

```
    %\begin{comment}
 \begin{figure}[H] 
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            legend style={
    legend columns=4,
        at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
        anchor=north,
        draw=none
    },
            ybar stacked,
            xlabel= Year,
            ylabel = USD bn,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            width =.90\textwidth,
            height = 1.3\textwidth,
            %xmin = 2005,
            %xmax = 2012,
            ymin = -6,
            ymax = 10000,
            ytick={0,1000,...,15000},
            % axis x line* = bottom,
            % axis y line* = left,
            xticklabels = none,
            extra x ticks = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014},
            extra x tick labels = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014},
            legend style={font=\footnotesize},
            %area legend,
            %scaled ticks = false,
            %y tick label style = {/pgf/number format/use comma}
            ]
            \addplot+[mark=none, fill=dbscan, draw = dbscan, bar width = 9mm] table[x=year, y=Donation] {Chapters/Chapter_2/Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt};
            \addplot+[mark=none, fill=red, draw = red, bar width = 9mm] table[x=year, y=Equity] {Chapters/Chapter_2/Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt};
            \addplot+[mark=none, fill=orange, draw = orange, bar width = 9mm] table[x=year, y=Lending] {Chapters/Chapter_2/Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt};
            \addplot+[mark=none, fill=black, draw = black, bar width = 9mm] table[x=year, y=Reward] {Chapters/Chapter_2/Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt};
            \addplot+[mark=none, fill=blue, draw = blue, bar width = 9mm] table[x=year, y=Mixed-others] {Chapters/Chapter_2/Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt};
            \addplot+[mark=none, fill=yellow, draw = yellow, bar width = 9mm] table[x=year, y=Total] {Chapters/Chapter_2/Value of Crowdfunding by type.txt};
            \legend{Donation, Equity, Lending, Reward, Mixed other, Total}
            %\coordinate (2013) at (8mm, 100);
        \end{axis} 
        %\node at (2013) {XY};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Testing}
    \label{Testing label}
    \floatfoot{\textit{Source}: Testing source}
\end{figure}
```

I'm stuck! Any help is appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error message regarding the missing columns in some rows. If I add a `0` in the last column (Total) for 2011, 2012 and 2013 the yellow bars start at bn=0.

If the legend should be only one line use

```
legend columns=-1,
```

The top and the right axis could be removed if you uncomment the following two lines in your code

```
axis x line* = bottom,
axis y line* = left,
```

or if you insert

```
axis lines*=left,
```

To get `nodes near coords` only for the yellow bars use `ymax=17000` and

```
\addplot+[fill=yellow, draw = yellow,
    nodes near coords,point meta=explicit% <- added
  ] table[x=year, y=Total,
    meta expr=\thisrow{Total}/1000% <- added
  ] {data.txt};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
year Donation Equity Lending Reward Mixed-others Total

2010 460.4 49.9 316.5 15.7 0 0
2011 675.7 88.9 554.9 61.5 0 0
2012 979.4 115.7 1169.7 383.3 2.4 0
2013 0 0 0 0 0 6100
2014 0 0 0 0 0 16200
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\colorlet{dbscan}{purple}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            legend style={
              legend columns=-1,% <- changed
              at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
              anchor=north,
              draw=none
            },
            axis lines*=left,% <- added
            ybar stacked,
            xlabel= Year,
            ylabel = USD bn,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            width =.90\textwidth,
            height = 1.3\textwidth,
            %xmin = 2005,
            %xmax = 2012,
            ymin = -6,
            ymax = 17000,% <- changed
            try min ticks=17,% <- added
            %ytick={0,1000,...,16000},% <- commented
            xticklabels = none,
            extra x ticks = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014},
            extra x tick labels = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014},
            legend style={font=\footnotesize},
            bar width=9mm% <- added
            ]
            \addplot+[fill=dbscan, draw = dbscan] table[x=year, y=Donation] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=red, draw = red] table[x=year, y=Equity] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=orange, draw = orange] table[x=year, y=Lending] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=black, draw = black] table[x=year, y=Reward] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=blue, draw = blue] table[x=year, y=Mixed-others] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=yellow, draw = yellow,
                nodes near coords,point meta=explicit% <- added
              ] table[x=year, y=Total,
                meta expr=\thisrow{Total}/1000% <- added
              ] {data.txt};
            \legend{Donation, Equity, Lending, Reward, Mixed other, Total}
            %\coordinate (2013) at (8mm, 100);
        \end{axis} 
        %\node at (2013) {XY};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** (because of a comment to this answer)

To change the color of the `nodes near coords` use

```
nodes near coords style={text=black}
```

and to divide the `y` values by 1000 use

y expr=\thisrow{}/1000

for every plot. Of course you have to change `ytick` too.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
year Donation Equity Lending Reward Mixed-others Total

2010 460.4 49.9 316.5 15.7 0 0
2011 675.7 88.9 554.9 61.5 0 0
2012 979.4 115.7 1169.7 383.3 2.4 0
2013 0 0 0 0 0 6100
2014 0 0 0 0 0 16200
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\colorlet{dbscan}{purple}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
        \begin{axis}[
            legend style={
              legend columns=-1,% <- changed
              at={(xticklabel cs:0.5)},
              anchor=north,
              draw=none
            },
            axis lines*=left,% <- added
            ybar stacked,
            xlabel= Year,
            ylabel = USD bn,
            %ymajorgrids = true,
            width =.90\textwidth,
            height = 1.3\textwidth,
            %xmin = 2005,
            %xmax = 2012,
            ymin = 0,
            ymax = 17,% <- changed
            ytick={0,...,17},%< - changed
            xticklabels = none,
            extra x ticks = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014},
            extra x tick labels = {2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014},
            legend style={font=\footnotesize},
            bar width=9mm% <- added
            ]
            \addplot+[fill=dbscan, draw = dbscan] table[x=year, y expr=\thisrow{Donation}/1000] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=red, draw = red] table[x=year, y expr=\thisrow{Equity}/1000] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=orange, draw = orange] table[x=year, y expr=\thisrow{Lending}/1000] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=black, draw = black] table[x=year, y expr=\thisrow{Reward}/1000] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=blue, draw = blue] table[x=year, y expr=\thisrow{Mixed-others}/1000] {data.txt};
            \addplot+[fill=yellow, draw = yellow,
                nodes near coords,point meta=explicit,% <- added
                nodes near coords style={text=black}% <- added
              ] table[x=year,
                y expr=\thisrow{Total}/1000,%<- changed
                meta expr=\thisrow{Total}/1000% <- added
              ] {data.txt};
            \legend{Donation, Equity, Lending, Reward, Mixed other, Total}
            %\coordinate (2013) at (8mm, 100);
        \end{axis} 
        %\node at (2013) {XY};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Briliant! It worked. Is it possible to change the green color inside the yellow bars? And also, is it possible to change the left axis so the values are 1.0, 2.0, 3.0...17.0 instead of 0.1, 0.2, 0.3...1.7 and also get rid of the "*10^4" in the top?

Comment: @Saud See my updated answer.